# Nested Selects in Nhibernate QueryOver

Tags: sql, nhibernate, hql, queryover

After my search, I haven't found anything really useful in helping me figure out where to proceed.

So far I have only written fairly simple nHibernate queries and have a relatively complex SQL one that I need to pump out in QueryOver (Icriteria) or if that proves too fiddly, HQL. Please find the query below:

```
Select aliasTable1.Id, AliasTable1.Time, 
       AlaisTable2.Version,
       (select top 1 secondAliasTable1.Time
          from Table1 secondAliasTable1
          where aliasTable1.Time < secondAliasTable1.Time
            AND secondAliasTable1.Time < (SELECT Top 1 thirdAliasTable1.Time from Table1 thirdAliasTable1 
                                            where thirdAliasTable1.Name = 'stringValue1'
                                              AND thirdAliasTable1.Id = aliasTable1.Id
                                              AND thirdAliasTable1.Time > aliasTable1.Time
                                            ORDER By thirdAliasTable1.Time)
            AND secondAliasTable1.Name = 'stringValue2'
            AND secondAliasTable1.Id = aliasTable1.Id
            ORDER BY secondAliasTable1.Time) As 'Endtime'
  from Table1 aliasTable1
    INNER JOIN Table2 aliasTable2 on AliasTable2.Id = aliasTable1.table2Id
  where alaisTable1.Name = 'stringValue2'
  ORDER BY alaisTable1.Time
```

I have really hit a wall with this query in the conversion, so I am hoping to get at least a starting point to get me going, if not a full answer!

Cheers

Comment: @henrique Thanks for the code edit. For some reason, I had trouble getting it to pick up anything but the first line of the query when I tried to put it in a code block.

Comment: I usually just select the whole code and click on the Code Sample button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will depend slightly on your mappings, but something like this should work:

```cs
Table1 aliasTable1 = null, secondAliasTable1 = null, thirdAliasTable1 = null;
Table2 aliasTable2 = null;

var result = session.QueryOver<Table1>(() => aliasTable1)
    .Where(p => p.Name == "stringValue1")
    .JoinQueryOver(p => p.Table2, () => aliasTable2)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(() => aliasTable1.Id)
        .Select(() => aliasTable1.Time)
        .Select(() => aliasTable2.Version)
        .SelectSubQuery(
            QueryOver.Of<Table1>(() => secondAliasTable1)
                .Where(() => aliasTable1.Time < secondAliasTable1.Time)
                .WithSubquery.Where(() => secondAliasTable1.Time <
                    QueryOver.Of<Table1>(() => thirdAliasTable1)
                        .Where(() => thirdAliasTable1.Name == "stringValue1")
                        .And(() => thirdAliasTable1.Id == aliasTable1.Id)
                        .And(() => thirdAliasTable1.Time > aliasTable1.Time)
                        .SelectList(inner => inner
                            .Select(() => thirdAliasTable1.Time))                            
                        .OrderBy(() => thirdAliasTable1.Time).Asc()
                        .Take(1)
                        .As<DateTime>())
                .And(() => secondAliasTable1.Name == "stringValue2")
                .And(() => secondAliasTable1.Id == aliasTable1.Id)
                .SelectList(third => third
                    .Select(() => secondAliasTable1.Time))
                .OrderBy(() => secondAliasTable1.Time).Asc()
                .Take(1)))
    .OrderBy(() => aliasTable1.Time).Asc()
    .List<object[]>();
```

This generates SQL that looks something like this:

```
SELECT this_.Id                            as y0_,
       this_.Time                          as y1_,
       aliastable1_.Version                as y2_,
       (SELECT TOP (1 /* @p0 */) this_0_.Time as y0_
        FROM   [Table1] this_0_
        WHERE  this_.Time < this_0_.Time
               and this_0_.Time < (SELECT TOP (1 /* @p1 */) this_0_0_.Time as y0_
                                             FROM   [Table1] this_0_0_
                                             WHERE  this_0_0_.Name = 'stringValue1' /* @p2 */
                                                    and this_0_0_.Id = this_.Id
                                                    and this_0_0_.Time > this_.Time
                                             ORDER  BY this_0_0_.Time asc)
               and this_0_.Name = 'stringValue2' /* @p3 */
               and this_0_.Id = this_.Id
        ORDER  BY this_0_.Time asc) as y3_
FROM   [Table1] this_
       inner join [Table2] aliastable1_
         on this_.Id = aliastable1_.Table1Id
WHERE  this_.Name = 'stringValue1' /* @p4 */
ORDER  BY this_.Time asc
```

Instead of `.List<object[]>()` you could also project to a DTO of your choice (using `TransformUsing`). If this looks overwhelming, I would strongly recommend breaking each detached `QueryOver` into it's own variable and then referencing them from the main query.

*Update:* If you want to use `.TransformUsing`, you need to create a `null` result object and use `.WithAlias()`:

```cs
Table1 aliasTable1 = null, secondAliasTable1 = null, thirdAliasTable1 = null;
Table2 aliasTable2 = null;
MyDTO dto = null;

var result = session.QueryOver<Table1>(() => aliasTable1)
    .Where(p => p.Name == "stringValue1")
    .JoinQueryOver(p => p.Table2, () => aliasTable2)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(() => aliasTable1.Id).WithAlias(() => dto.Id)
        .Select(() => aliasTable1.Time).WithAlias(() => dto.Time)
        .Select(() => aliasTable2.Version).WithAlias(() => dto.Version)
        .SelectSubQuery(
            QueryOver.Of<Table1>(() => secondAliasTable1)
                .Where(() => aliasTable1.Time < secondAliasTable1.Time)
                .WithSubquery.Where(() => secondAliasTable1.Time <
                    QueryOver.Of<Table1>(() => thirdAliasTable1)
                        .Where(() => thirdAliasTable1.Name == "stringValue1")
                        .And(() => thirdAliasTable1.Id == aliasTable1.Id)
                        .And(() => thirdAliasTable1.Time > aliasTable1.Time)
                        .SelectList(inner => inner
                            .Select(() => thirdAliasTable1.Time))                            
                        .OrderBy(() => thirdAliasTable1.Time).Asc()
                        .Take(1)
                        .As<DateTime>())
                .And(() => secondAliasTable1.Name == "stringValue2")
                .And(() => secondAliasTable1.Id == aliasTable1.Id)
                .SelectList(third => third
                    .Select(() => secondAliasTable1.Time))
                .OrderBy(() => secondAliasTable1.Time).Asc()
                .Take(1)).WithAlias(() => dto.Time2))
    .OrderBy(() => aliasTable1.Time).Asc()
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<MyDTO>())
    .List<MyDTO>();
```

Comment: I already have the DTO set up to project to, and have it sort of working using CreateSQLQuery. I will try this that you have offered up and get back to you on it.

Comment: @DavidWatts: Okay, let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: For some reason, the fourth column I am trying to pull is always being thrown as null. I am wanting to return these columns, in order Id, Start Time, Version, End Time. End time is pulled from the same table as the start time, but from a different field, referenced by name. I'm sure you understood that from my question, but It is always being returned as null. Any Ideas?

Comment: I don't know if you saw this, as I don't know if it referenced you properly

Comment: Oh and one more thing... When I return a list of object arrays, I get the results back ok, but using this `.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TimeComparisonObject>()).List<TimeComparisonObject>();` at the end of the query sets all of the items within the object as null.

Comment: Does the SQL return similar results? As for the `.TransformUsing` code, I'll add an update to my answer.

Comment: Hi andrew, I found the issue in the SQL, there was an equals where there should have been a >, and when it is returned to a list of object arrays, everything is populated ok, and I have used the `Transformers.AliasToBean<TimeComparisonObject>` and I have projected everything using the `projections.property` followed by the `.WithAlias` and it has worked for all but the end date. The projection for that is on the select within the selectsubquery just before the order by.

Comment: I'm going to upvote you anyway if rep will allow me, as the query is Technically working, but its now the projections causing the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is the `WithAlias` placement you mentioned--It should be right after `.SelectSubquery` (the same position it's in after the other `Select`s)

Comment: Still not working. Please can you update your answer with the `Projections.Property` code as well as the `WithAlias` code, as I cannot see where this needs to be inserted to make it work. The code above makes the last OrderBy an invalid option to use.

Comment: You shouldn't need `Projections.Property` here. Make sure the `.WithAlias` calls are in just the right place. Unfortunately I can't really see the results being populated since I'm using my own database tables and the query doesn't really make sense in that context...

Answer (score 0):

With HQL, assuming you've already mapped your Entities to your Tables:

The Joins could be done explicitly, this way:

```
Select aliasTable1.Id, aliasTable2.Version
  from Table1 as aliasTable1
    JOIN aliasTable1.table2 as aliasTable2;
```

Also, I'm not sure if you can have Top in Inner Queries in HQL, so you could change those to something like:

```
AND secondAliasTable1.Time < (SELECT max(thirdAliasTable1.Time) from Table1 as thirdAliasTable1 
                                where thirdAliasTable1.Name = 'stringValue1'
                                  AND thirdAliasTable1.Id = aliasTable1.Id
                                  AND thirdAliasTable1.Time > aliasTable1.Time)
```

Also, if you want your query to return a List of a DTO containing only those 4 Properties (id, time, version and endTime) you should look at Transformers.aliasToBean().

I wrote something about that once here: http://hordine.com/?p=1187